# I cannot see table on oracle 10g after successful importing the dmp file

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I am new for Oracle
Here our client provide the the exported file in .dmp file, and the .dmp file is exported in 6i oracle. 
Now, i am trying to import the file in oracle 10g express edition. I tried the same thing in 11g enterprise edition with **impdp** command, but **didn't work** and i **found my mistake** to; it **can only be done  via imp** command. And doing  same thing in oracle 10g express edition. Here i went along with following steps:

1. Create User(for shcema)

   ```
   create user veshraj identified by veshraj
   //granting some priviliges
   grant connect, create, imp_full_database to veshraj
   ```
2. Imposing the imp command via CLI

   ```
   imp  // press enter
   //asks for user name and password i provide new user name and password
   //it provides following lines
   import file EXPDAT.DMP> c:\db\motor.dmp
   // it asks for number of bytes and i provide the maximum value
   List contents of import file only (yes/no): no >Y
   Import entire export file (yes/no): no >Y
   // provides following results
   "ALTER SESSION SET "_LOAD_WITHOUT_COMPILE" = NONE"
   "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA= "ADMIN""
   "ALTER PACKAGE "PACK_DC" COMPILE REUSE SETTINGS TIMESTAMP '2007-02-22:11:13:" "07'"
   "ALTER PACKAGE "PACK_MOTOR" COMPILE REUSE SETTINGS TIMESTAMP 2006-12-10:14:" "54:12'"
   "ALTER PACKAGE "PACK_NW" COMPILE REUSE SETTINGS TIMESTAMP '2006-10-16:11:55:" "48'"
   "ALTER TABLE "MISCH_REFUND" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("PRIMARY_NO") " "REFERENCES "MISCH_MASTER" ("PRIMARY_NO") ENABLE           "
   "ALTER TABLE "AD_LEAVE" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_AD_LEAVE" FOREIGN KEY ("EID") REFERENCES "AD_EMP" ("EID") ENABLE NOVALIDATE"
   "ALTER TABLE "INT_DET" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_INT_DET" FOREIGN KEY ("PRIMARY_NO""") REFERENCES "LAGANI" ("PRIMARY_NO") ENABLE           "
   "ALTER TABLE "LOAN_INF" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_LOAN" FOREIGN KEY ("PRIMARY_NO") "REFERENCES "LOAN_DET" ("PRIMARY_NO") ENABLE           "
   "ALTER TABLE "MONC_DET" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_MONC" FOREIGN KEY ("FISCAL_YEAR") REFERENCES "MONC_MASTER" ("FISCAL_YEAR") ENABLE NOVALIDATE"
   // and many more alter table information
   // final message is follows
   Import terminated successfully without warnings.
   ```

but problem is that i cant not see any tables(imported) somewhere in oracle 10g. What should i do for things getting done.

Comment: There is no version 6i of the database; you're presumably referring to Oracle Forms 6i, but that doesn't tell you which version of the database the dump file came from. At least 10g since it didn't complain. And you can use the legacy `imp` with 11g too, not just 10g, if you want to. Do you know which schema the export was done from? You may need to use the FROMUSER and TOUSER arguments too.

Comment: actually I use the information provided by co-worker, thanks for your response. I did it, the problem was with the name of schema,  it needs to be same as exported one. But FROMUSER and TOUSER arguments seems to be invalid in 10g. I may have wrong concept while writing syntax. Thanks a lot Lalit Kumar B, i will follow your words to.

Comment: [FROMUSER is valid](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#sthref2427). Maybe you tried to use it and FULL at the same time, which is not? Well, at least you got it working somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> List contents of import file only (yes/no): no >Y

This is the equivalent of [the SHOW parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#sthref2498). You said yes, so the contents are listed, and no data is imported. Re-run your import but say no to that prompt.

Comment: Excellent tip. Made my day!